# How to get hotmail to accept my mails

Tags: email, spam-prevention, hotmail

Hotmail keeps rejecting my mails for undisclosed reasons with a code `550 SC-001`

```
Mail rejected by Outlook.com for policy reasons. 
Reasons for rejection may be related to content with spam-like characteristics or IP/domain reputation.
If you are not an email/network admin please contact your Email/Internet Service Provider for help.
```

It seems like they require more antispam features.

I deployed:

- DKIM
- SPF with `+a +mx ~all` (`~all` to avoid breaking mailinglists).
- DMARC with `v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; pct=100; adkim=s; aspf=r;fo=1; ruf=mailto:[adminmailaddress]; ri=604800`
- The reverse DNS of the sending IP resolves to the sending IP.
- A Multi-RBL test tells me, the IP is listed in no spam list.

Comment: what email domain are you sending from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hotmail tends to be quite harsh sometimes regarding to new domains or domains they don't have info about. If you *really* have all what you mentioned running, the only thing left is IP reputation.

For that, Microsoft has [a form](https://support.live.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl3&ct=eformts) which will lead to a revision on their part. They will usually whitelist your domain, but that doesn't mean that initially your mails won't end up in the `Spam` folder of your users, they just won't get rejected.

You'll have to gain some reputation after a time, with patience and encouraging your users to click on the <kbd>This is not spam</kbd> button for your mails.

Comment: Also, setting up `DMARC` might help you, not just with Hotmail but generally.

Comment: I already use DMARC, i put my Record into the Question.

Comment: Reputation is a bit a problem, as it bounces the mails. If it would put them into spam, it would not be a big problem, as users could at least find and maybe whitelist them and the server could build a reputation. The domain is not new and the server ip did not change for a while as well.

Comment: Then it might be a problem related to a compromised account or some strange activity on your side. Anyway, the form link I provided works for these situations as well. At least they will tell you what the problem is, possibly they will whitelist your domain and you can fix the issue.

Comment: I sent them a request. I just thought maybe some configuration is missing and fixing it will help with hotmail.

Comment: If you have everything that you mention, I see no reason for hard reject your mails (I have several domains with these ingredients and they have not been blocked, so I assume something unusual happened on your side).

Comment: I am pretty sure there is nothing bad happening. No log entries, no strange network traffic, never were on a ip blacklist.
The only thing special about the mail, which i could test some time, was a pgp signature as attachment. Maybe they are more strict when there are (binary) attachments.